# how to parse below Json android

Tags: android, json

i have below Json to Parse. I am doing it by means of multiple if else loop . is there is any standard way to parse such json format.? 
Please provide any help..

```
JSON: 

{
"Info": {
        "DeviceInfo": {
            "Version": "NA",
            "IMEI"   : "NA",
            "IMSI"   : "NA",
            "Manufacture" : "NA",
            "Network"     : "NA",
            "Root"        : "NA",
            "Storage"     : "NA"
        },
        "SettingInfo": {
            "Brightness": "NA",
            "FlightMode": "NA"
        },
        "AdvanceInfo": {
            "PictureCount": "NA",
            "VideoCount": "NA",
            "CallIn": "NA",
            "CallOut":"NA"
        },
        "MemoryInfo": {
            "RAM": "NA",
            "ReadSpeedInternal": "NA",
            "WriteSpeedInternal": "NA"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the Gson or Jackson libraries do the hard work for you, there is no need to do the parsing yourself,

GSON: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md
Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

For further reference see https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
String in;
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);

JSONObject info = reader.getJSONObject("Info");
JSONObject deviceInfo = info.getJSONObject("DeviceInfo");
String version = deviceInfo.getString("Version");
String imei = deviceInfo.getString("IMEI");
String imsi = deviceInfo.getString("IMSI");
```

Here is more information + example:

[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm